# C# Using SQL Method needs a close-method?

Tags: c#, sql, connection, using

When using a `using` block for SQL connections in C#, does this also a close method? I'm asking as I need to explicitly use the `con.Open()` method. I found this example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   con.Open(); // open method

   string queryString = "select * from db";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   reader.Read();

   ???         // What about a close method?
}
```

Or does the `using` block close the connection itself?

Comment: using will call Dispose of connection and Dispose will call Close.

Comment: so when Im using it, using will close all connetions. All connections means global, or only this connections in this method/class where it is?

Comment: @ManuelFischer only connection in statement using(SqlConnection iWillDisposeConn = new...

Comment: You should really have your command and reader in `using` blocks also - they're disposable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` translates to:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
try
{
   con.Open(); <-- open method

   string queryString = "select * from db";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   reader.Read();
}
finally
{
    if (con!= null)
        ((IDisposable)con).Dispose();
}
```

where `((IDisposable)con.Dispose();` closes what is to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close it - `using` is enough. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) says:

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to call the `Close`-Method of the `SqlConnection`.
When it gets disposed on the end of the using, it closes automatically.
(The `Dispose`-Method calls `Close()`) [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/aa326260%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, however, I want to be a bit more explicit.
The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2728ad.aspx) states the following:

> **Close** and **Dispose** are functionally equivalent.

Because using `using` will call `Dispose` a separate call to `Close` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the 'using' keyword  and create  a connection in it .
the connection is open as far as there is the scope of the 'using' keyword when closing bracket is reached the connection is closed automatically as it was defined within a scope and the scope is not in exist

in other words treat it as the local variable which can be accessed within the scope only.
hope this will help.